# Is it possible to make a Twitter Bootstrap modal slide from the side or bottom instead of sliding down?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently the modal slide down effect is done by adding the `fade` class to the modal div. Is it possible to change the effect to sliding from the side (or from the bottom) by changing the css?  I couldn't find any information online on how to do this and don't know enough css to do this myself.

html:

```
<div id='test-modal' class='modal fade hide'>
  <div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, could you change the accepted answer to dave's? Mine is now outdated.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 now uses CSS transform translate3d instead of CSS transitions for better animations using GPU hardware acceleration.

It uses the following CSS (sans easing)

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
}
```

Here is CSS you can use to slide in from the LEFT side

```
.modal.fade:not(.in) .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}
```

Notice the negative selector. I noticed this was necessary to keep the ".modal.in .modal-dialog" definition from interfering. *Note: I am not a CSS guru, so if anyone can better explain this, feel free :)*

How to slide in from different sides:

- top: `translate3d(0, -25%, 0)`
- bottom: `translate3d(0, 25%, 0)`
- left: `translate3d(-25%, 0, 0)`
- right: `translate3d(25%, 0, 0)`

---

If you want to mix and match different slide directions, you can assign a class like 'left' to the modal...

```
<div class="modal fade left">
    ...
</div>
```

...and then target that specifically with CSS:

```
.modal.fade:not(.in).left .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}
```

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/mu5mvba0/

**BONUS** - You could get a little zany and slide in at an angle:

- top-left: `translate3d(-25%, -25%, 0)`
- top-right: `translate3d(25%, -25%, 0)`
- bottom-left: `translate3d(-25%, 25%, 0)`
- bottom-right: `translate3d(25%, 25%, 0)`

*UPDATE (05/28/15): I updated the fiddle to display the alternative angles*

---

If you want to use this in a LESS template, you can use BS3's vendor-prefix mixin (as long as it's included)

```
.modal.fade:not(.in) .modal-dialog {
    .translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove the sliding and just keep the fadeIn?

Comment: @MustafaS - you'd just set the transform/-webkit-transform property to "none"

Comment: Setting the values to 125% / -125% makes that transformation 5 times quicker than 25% / -25%.  Setting them to 25% / -25% to match the others ensures the slide effects are all at the same speed.

Comment: @olimortimer - thanks! I have no idea why I did that. I probably was just tinkering around with different speeds and forgot to make them uniform in the answer :P I updated the answer. I also went ahead and updated the fiddle and also added the alternative angles if anyone wanted to see what they looked like too.

Comment: Added a Sass version of the fiddle for anyone working in LESS/SCSS to make it easier to add to your project (obviously the variable needs to be changed to `@modal-speed` if you're working in LESS) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/96L8rtuh/)

Comment: @dave - No worries! Excellent solution! Used this in my project to mimic iOS modals flying in from the right.

Comment: Updated SCSS version: http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/0tgquLuh/ (accidentally removed the old one - would be nice to attach a name/lock to fiddles!)

Comment: You could set the modal to show from left and hide to right using these CSS http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/mu5mvba0/ and this piece of code `$('#ContactFormModal').prop('class', 'modal fade').addClass('left');` (use it before shoing the modal) and `$('#ContactFormModal').removeClass('left').addClass('right');` (use it after modal i shown). It's not full code but you will get the idea.

Comment: LOL well that's a very informative rebuttal, RolandiXor. I just updated the fiddle to the latest version of Bootstrap 3 (3.3.6) and it works, so the problem is on your end. If you're using Bootstrap 4, that would be helpful information; I haven't used it yet so I wouldn't know what's different.

Comment: the bootstrap 3 use uses translate(x,y) instead of translate3D(z,y,z) so sliding from right is transform:translate(25%,0)

Answer (score 28):

**This information is outdated. Bootstrap 3 handles this differently now. Please see [the updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25718426/168175) if you are using the newer version**.

The "slide-in" transition is in fact handled by the bootstrap css. In particular, it is handled by this part:

```
// bootstrap.css

.modal.fade {
  top: -25%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.fade.in {
  top: 50%;
}
```

To change the transition direction, just add (in your **own** stylesheet, because the bootstrap css will be updated in future versions) these styles. These will overwrite the bootstrap styles. To have the modal slide in from the left, try:

```
.modal.fade {
  left: -25%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.fade.in {
  left: 50%;
}​
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HdVyn/1/).

To transition from the right to left, supply a *large positive* percentage for the modal to transition from, and change the modal's final resting place to the respective direction.
e.g. `.modal.fade { left: 200%; } ... .modal.fade.in { left: 50% };`

[Right to left example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xgkqP/1/)

[Bottom to top example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xgkqP/2/)

More info on [CSS Transitions here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: Is it possible to have the exit go the other direction? eg it enters in from the left and exits (on closing) to the right?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @persistence I suppose it would be possible, but the nature of the CSS transition means that it starts at the position in `.modal.fade` and animates to the position in `.modal.fade.in`. To have it transition out a different direction I suppose you could catch the modal `.on('hide', function()...)` event and change the `.modal.fade` position before it starts moving. That would be how I would approach it. And then once it is finished animating, when `.on('hidden', function()...` fires, you could change the `.modal.fade` position back to what it was before. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should also add `top: 50%;` to `.modal.fade` to ensure that it transitions out properly, instead of just disappearing.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi This worked 4 years ago in Bootstrap 2, I'd be surprised if it was still working. You're likely using Bootstrap 3 and should use the approach in the accepted answer.

Comment: @rosshamish. My bad. Thanks for the clarification. I missed out the Bootstrap 2 part.

Comment: It's not working as it's missing the Bootstrap, I uppdated it now with Bootstrap

Answer (score 8):

This is for someone who is looking for **Bootstrap 4** solution:

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSidePaneRight">Slide Right Panel</a>

<div class="modal fade modal-right-pane" id="modalSidePaneRight" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sidePaneRightModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="sidePaneRightModal"><i class="fi fi-calender"></i> Your Modal Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body bg-primary">
        <h1>Your Content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
/*******************************
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add ".modal-left-pane" or ".modal-right-pane" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
*******************************/

// Modal Panel: Right
$header-nav-height: 56px;
$modal-height: calc(100vh - #{$header-nav-height});

.modal{
  &.modal-left-pane,
  &.modal-right-pane {
    .modal-dialog {
      max-width: 380px;
      min-height: $modal-height;
    }

    &.show .modal-dialog {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }

    .modal-content {
      min-height: $modal-height;
    }
  }
  &.modal-left-pane {
    .modal-dialog {
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      margin: $header-nav-height auto 0 0;
    }
  }

  &.modal-right-pane {
    .modal-dialog {
      transform: translate(100%, 0);
      margin: $header-nav-height 0 0 auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, very helpful comment, but i think the op asked, if it was possible for the slide animation to not be from top to bottom, but instead from left to right or right to left. Can you please tell us what we need to add for the `modal-left-pane` to slide from left of the screen not from top of the screen.