# Is there a way to launch a Bootstrap 3 Modal from the point of click?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have found one option to launch a modal from the center of the screen: [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/twitter-boostrap-modal/full_screen_preview/3794635)
and another that provides more easing options: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i).  But none of these give me any custom controls...

I am looking for more control.  Are there any options.

Comment: You mean, when a user clicks to show a modal? Or make a modal appear at the coordinates a user clicks?

Comment: the former..  when a user clicks expand the modal from that point to show at its default location

Comment: So is your specific request to be able to control the animation of the modal? You want it to be able to animate from pointer position to a default/center location?