# How can I change the direction of the bootstrap modal opening?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the opening direction of my bootstrap reveal modal. I Followed the code as discussed in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i) but my modal is not opening, I'm using `angularjs`.
Can anyone help me with the code?

my button

```
<td>
    <a class='btn btn-primary btn' data-direction='right'>Right</a>
</td>
```

bootstrap `Bootstrap v3.2.0`

my CSS and JS as as mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i). 
How can I use it with angular,its not working in my case.

Comment: Please post some code in your question...

Comment: Bootstrap version as well as code needed

Comment: @user284303 Honestly, you're going to have to do better than that. The one line of code you're giving us doesn't help at all. What CSS is in your stylesheet? How are you declaring your modal?

Answer (score 0):

To get a modal to open, you can use javascript or data attributes. You seem to be using neither.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Notice the `data-toggle` attribute - This tells bootstrap that it's a modal and it should be opened as one.

Notice the `data-target` attribute - This is the container of your modal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the transition of CSS.

Here is the very simple example for opening direction.

(SlideLeftIn Transition Effect)

```css
.modal .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal .modal-dialog.show {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: left 0.35s;
}
```

For more information see [this from W3Schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_js_transition)