# Bootstrap modal: sideway slide in and out

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap's modal to do a series of reviews. So I queued up a bunch of modals in a list and shows the next one after the user has reviewed the current one.

Question: how do I change the modal so that the current one slides out to the left, and the new one slides in from the right?

I would like this to be a new class that I can apply to these specific modals. I'm using modals elsewhere on the site for which I like Bootstrap's default behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

OK it was stupid not to post any code, so here's a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/1BADCJo5FL#

The trick is in the CSS markups, where you change the default starting position here with a `right: 25%;` ...

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
```

... and how it moves once it's shown with a transform

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(25%, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(25%, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(25%, 0);
          transform: translate(25%, 0);
}
```

Now this is interesting: bootstrap only has a CSS markup for `modal.in`, and no `modal.out`. It seems to simply go back the way it came from. I'm not sure if this is just default CSS behavior or what....

So this is doing half of what I want, but would be nice to have the thing move more like... I guess a carousel.

Comment: Please post the related code in a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @vanburenx added a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/1BADCJo5FL#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a Twitter Bootstrap modal slide from the side or bottom instead of sliding down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i)

Comment: @reedvoid See the answer. is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

I have just changed few codes in jquery. add a class called `close` while closing the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#show_normal').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal').removeClass('out');
  });

  $('#hide_normal').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $('#myModal').addClass('out');
  });
```

});

and added a few codes in css

```
.modal.fade.out {    
   right: -25%;
   left: auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
 }
```

you can see the live demo on http://www.bootply.com/bz1VioVHpI