# Change animation of bootstrap modal on close button to slide left

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which slides from left to right when a button is clicked. I want to make it slide back from right to left, when the modal close button is clicked. Just want to reverse the animation on close button, At the moment is has the default bootstrap modal behaviour for the close button. Below is the code.

Live link : http://www.babaraliseehar.com/onepage/index.php
click on compare button to display the modal.

```
    .modal.fade:not(.in).right .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
}

#modal h2 {
    margin:0;
}
#modal .copy,#modal .header, #modal .footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.modal-content {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;

}
#modal .copy {
    background: #fff;
}

#modal .overlay {
    background-color: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Check these links for solution: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa 
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i

Comment: Yes, I had already checked both the links, but I want the slide effect from right to left when I click on the close button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a Twitter Bootstrap modal slide from the side or bottom instead of sliding down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465221/is-it-possible-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-slide-from-the-side-or-bottom-i)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. added data-direction='left' to the close button and for css

```
    .modal.fade:not(.in).left .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}
```